# Building spring org.springframework.cglib.proxy source code not found

Tags: java, spring

I'm diving into spring's source code,but when I did that,it showed me some errors about the cglib classes-Saying that the compiler can not find the classes.
Something like these classes:
Callback,CallbackFilter,Enhancer,MethodInterceptor,etc.
All these classes are in cglib package,but when I check the github for the latest source code(I updated my repository to make sure it is the latest master branch.),I can not found the classes too.
I checked spring's release package,it contains the classes listed above.

Is anyone can tell me,whether there is something wrong with spring's source code?Or if I'm in the wrong way,that the classes is generated by the cglib itself,not by someone else?

Thanks.

Comment: CGlib isn't Spring, have a look at http://cglib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup Yes,I known that.But org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback and the other similar classes is in the spring's package inside the spring-core.jar,but when I check the source code,I can not found these source code,I just want to know where I can find these source code.

Comment: What is the exact error that is shown?

Comment: @aksappy It produced errors like can not resolved Callback, and the other classes is the same info.

Comment: Just took the latest from mvnrepository and there are no issues. Are you really looking at releases?

Comment: Maven's mvnrepository is ok.The problem is in the classes that the class org.springframework.cglib.SpringCglibInfo refer to.But I found the package info for some defail,those classes are not available in the package.Thanks all the same.@aksappy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGLib is being replaced by Javassist in the master branch (for 4.x release) probably. You need to check 3.x branches on GitHub to find the source codes.

---

**UPDATE:** seems that this is not the case. Related issue https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8190 is still on backlog.

---

**UPDATE2:** These classes are just copies of classes from CGLIB. Check JavaDoc for the package http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cglib/package-summary.html:

> Spring's repackaging of net.sf.cglib 3 (for internal use only).
>
> This repackaging technique avoids any potential conflicts with
>   dependencies on CGLIB at the application level or from other
>   third-party libraries and frameworks.
>
> As this repackaging happens at the classfile level, sources and
>   Javadoc are not available here. See the [original CGLIB 3 Javadoc](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs) for
>   details when working with these classes.

Comment: Oh,I see.Those classes are created on runtime.Thanks Pavel.

Comment: Not on runtime, but during building phase - https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/build.gradle#L178 .